# How do I assign a default property to a FunctionProcedureName() in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, function, loops, recursion, parameter-passing

I have done extensive research on using recursion in VB.NET (I am using 2015) in order complete a homework assignment. In my desperation, I even asked my professor for help!

I am trying to write a program that will calculate 1! through 12!, and post the results in a list box. The method I am using is based on the following example (sent to me by my prof):

```
var integer n, result
n = 0

For 1 to 12 do
n = n + 1
write (n, ‘! equals ‘, Fact(n)
End For

Function Fact (ByVal n as Integer)
if (n = 0) then Fact = 1
else  Fact = n * Fact (n-1)
End If
End Function
```

http://www.softwareandfinance.com/VB/Factorial_Recursion.html

My issue is with my call statement for the function (I named it Factorial). Here is the section of the code where I am getting the error message:

```
        For intN = 1 To 12
            intFact = Factorial()
            lstFactorialsAnswers.Items.Add(intN & "! = " & intFact)
        Next
```

Thank you for your insights.

In response, I removed the "Dim Factorial as Int64" declaration. I also added "intN" as a parameter in the function call. The new error message is "Argument not specified for parameter 'intFact' of 'Public Function Factorial(intN As Integer, intFact As Integer) As Long'.

Here is the revised code:

```
Public Class frmFactorialMath

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    Dim intN As Integer
    Dim intFact As Integer
    intN = Convert.ToInt32(txtN)

    For intN = 1 To 12
        If intN = 1 Then
            lstFactorialsAnswers.Items.Add(intN & "! = " & 1)
        Else
            intFact = Factorial(intN)
            lstFactorialsAnswers.Items.Add(intN & "! = " & intFact)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function Factorial(ByVal intN As Integer, intFact As Integer) As Long

    If (intN = 0) Then
        Return 1
    Else
        intFact = intN * Factorial(intN - 1)
        Return intFact
    End If
End Function
```

Here is the solution to the issue(s) I was having:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class frmFactorialMath
   ' This event handler calculates the factorials for numbers 1 through   12.
   ' A list showing the answers is compiled and displayed.

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

      Dim intN, intFact As Integer

      For intN = 1 To 12
        intFact = Factorial(intN)
        lstFactorialsAnswers.Items.Add(intN.ToString() & "! = " & intFact.ToString())
      Next
  End Sub
' This Function performs the calculations using recursion.
Function Factorial(ByVal intFact As Integer) As Integer

    If intFact = 1 Then
        Return 1
    Else
        ' This "Do While" loop ends the recursion, eliminating an infinite loop.

        Do While intFact > 1
            Return intFact * Factorial(intFact - 1)
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: In your image you show `Dim Factorial as Int64` and you also have the function called `Factorial`. When you try to do `intFact = Factorial` it thinks the variable `Factorial` is a property instead of executing the function. Your function takes parameters but you havent given any, which is why the assignment is opting for the variable

Comment: Your Factorial function needs two parameters.  You supplied none.

Comment: Please post code not pictures of code.  It is easier to process what you are doing and provides better context